# Sitewide variables in Yesod layout (django context processors analog)

Tags: haskell, yesod

Is there a possibility to have a sitewide variables in Yesod? Suppose, I have main menu which entries are gathered from DB and that is rendered on every page: should i fetch entries manually in each handler?

I've tried to do this in Foundation.hs in `instance Yesod App` declaration in `defaultLayout`:

```
    instance Yesod App where
    ...

    defaultLayout widget = do
      ...
      entries <- runDB $ selectList [RubricOnTop ==. True] []
      ...
```

But this fails to compile: i have a type mismatch `Entity` with `RubricGeneric`.

**Solution**

```
    $forall rubric <- map entityVal rubrics
      ...
```

in default-layout-wrapper.hamlet. Haven't found solution to do this in defaultLayout function yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you've shown is fine, but you'll need to keep in mind when using `entries` that the type is `Entity Rubric`, not `Rubric`.