# Yesod persistent type error

Tags: haskell, yesod

I am trying out persistent in a Yesod application. My model file contains

```
Job
 issuer MemberId
 addDate UTCTime
 lastDate UTCTime
 title Text
 description Text
 deriving Show Read
```

And my Handler:

```
getProfileR :: Handler RepHtml
getProfileR = do
 jobs <- runDB $ selectList [] [Desc JobAddDate]
 defaultLayout $ do
  setTitle "title"
  $(widgetFile "profile")
```

In profile.hamlet I loop trough the objects

```
$forall Job issuer addDate lastDate title description <- jobs
 <p>#{issuer}
```

However, I get the following error

```
Handler/Profile.hs:36:18:
    Couldn't match type `Entity' with `JobGeneric'
    In the return type of a call of `selectList'
    In the second argument of `($)', namely
      `selectList [] [Desc JobAddDate]'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block:
      jobs <- runDB $ selectList [] [Desc JobAddDate]

Handler/Profile.hs:36:18:
    Kind incompatibility when matching types:
      t0 :: (* -> *) -> * -> *
      JobGeneric Database.Persist.GenericSql.Raw.SqlPersist :: *
    In the return type of a call of `selectList'
    In the second argument of `($)', namely
      `selectList [] [Desc JobAddDate]'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block:
      jobs <- runDB $ selectList [] [Desc JobAddDate]
Build failure, pausing...
```

Where line 36 is the runDB line.

Being new to Haskell, I can't figure out whats wrong. I am following the Yesod Book. They are unfortunately avoiding the Scaffolded Site so I can't completely mimic their code.

Comment: Perhaps [this question and it's answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11148074/sitewide-variables-in-yesod-layout-django-context-processors-analog) will be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`selectList` does not return `[Job]`, it's actually `[Entity Job]` which contains both the `Job` and its `Key`*

There are a number of ways to refactor this to handle it, one would be:

```
$forall Entity jobId job <- jobs
    <p>#{jobIssuer job}
```

In your template.

Alternatively, you can use `map entityVal` at any point to turn `[Entity Job] -> [Job]` if you'd prefer to work with that.

*The `Entity` and `Key` types are actually a bit more complex, but I find it's easier to think about them this way. Please read the docs if you're interested.