# How should I create a selectFieldList with using runDB function to fetch values?

Tags: haskell, yesod, yesod-forms

I would like to add a selectionFieldList to my Form, but unfortunetlly I could not fill with values from DB beacuse I got compile error.

I have form definition like this:

```
flowerForm = renderDivs $ FormFlower
<$> areq textField "Flower" Nothing
<*> areq (selectFieldList findAllAsTuple) "Category" Nothing
```

And the findAllAsTuple function :

```
findAllAsTuple ::[(Text,Text)]
findAllAsTuple = fmap (map (\cat -> (categoryName $ entityVal cat, categoryName $ entityVal cat))) $ runDB $ selectList [] [Asc CategoryName]
```

But I got this  error:

```
Handler\Category.hs:6:18:
Couldn't match type `HandlerT site0 IO' with `[]'
Expected type: [(Text, Text)]
  Actual type: HandlerT site0 IO [(Text, Text)]
In the expression:
  fmap
    (map
       (\ cat
          -> (categoryName $ entityVal cat, categoryName $ entityVal cat)))
  $ runDB $ selectList [] [Asc CategoryName]
In an equation for `findAllAsTuple':
    findAllAsTuple
      = fmap
          (map
             (\ cat
                -> (categoryName $ entityVal cat, categoryName $ entityVal cat)))
        $ runDB $ selectList [] [Asc CategoryName]
```

If I delete the fmap I got this error:

```
Handler\Category.hs:6:95:
Couldn't match expected type `[Entity Category]'
            with actual type `HandlerT site0 IO [Entity Category]'
In the second argument of `($)', namely
  `runDB $ selectList [] [Asc CategoryName]'
In the expression:
  map
    (\ cat
       -> (categoryName $ entityVal cat, categoryName $ entityVal cat))
  $ runDB $ selectList [] [Asc CategoryName]
In an equation for `findAllAsTuple':
    findAllAsTuple
      = map
          (\ cat
             -> (categoryName $ entityVal cat, categoryName $ entityVal cat))
        $ runDB $ selectList [] [Asc CategoryName]
```

I tried this way as well :

```
findAllAsTuple ::[(Text,Text)]
findAllAsTuple = do
            items <-  runDB $ selectList [] [Asc CategoryName]
            return $ map (\cat -> (categoryName $ entityVal cat,      categoryName $ entityVal cat))  items
```

But I then got this :

```
Handler\Category.hs:8:17:
Couldn't match type `[(Text, Text)]' with `(Text, Text)'
Expected type: [(Text, Text)]
  Actual type: [[(Text, Text)]]
In a stmt of a 'do' block:
  return
  $ map
      (\ cat
         -> (categoryName $ entityVal cat, categoryName $ entityVal cat))
      items
In the expression:
  do { items <- runDB $ selectList [] [Asc CategoryName];
       return
       $ map
           (\ cat
              -> (categoryName $ entityVal cat, categoryName $ entityVal cat))
           items }
In an equation for `findAllAsTuple':
    findAllAsTuple
      = do { items <- runDB $ selectList [] [Asc CategoryName];
             return
             $ map
                 (\ cat
                    -> (categoryName $ entityVal cat, categoryName $ entityVal cat))
                 items }
```

I do not understand why. If I write a simple map function like this :

```
 findAllAsTuple ::[(Text,Text)]
 findAllAsTuple =  map (\cat -> (cat,cat))  ["red","blue","yellow"]
```

It is work well and I do not get any type error.

Comment: I know nothing about yesod, but... shouldn't the type be `HandlerT something IO [(Text, Text)]` as GHC reports? I would be very surprised if you could access the database and return a pure list `[(Text,Text)]`. That type indicates that you can generate the list without accessing any data outside what's in the Haskell source (hence, not the DB).

Comment: I expected runDB function returns with [Entity Category] see here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11285419/yesod-persistent-type-error

Comment: According to the docs: `runDB :: YesodPersist site => YesodDB site a -> HandlerT site IO a`, so it does return something inside the Handler monad. https://www.fpcomplete.com/hoogle?q=runDB&env=ghc-7.8-stable-14.09

Comment: Yes i know that, that why I tried to use fmap and later do notation to unpack the item, but It did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution.

My function should look like this :

```
findAllAsTuple :: HandlerT App IO (OptionList Text)
findAllAsTuple =do 
             items <- runDB $ selectList [] [Asc CategoryName] 
             optionsPairs $ map (\c -> (categoryName $ entityVal    c,categoryName $ entityVal c)) items
```

Dmitry was right I should use selectField instead of selectFieldList.

The `optionsPairs` will create the OptionList from result. 
This question was duplicated : [Capturing Persistent Relations in a Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17778494/capturing-persistent-relations-in-a-form)

Answer (score 2):

Type of `findAllAsTuple` is `HandlerT site IO [(Text, Text)]`. 
You can check it in GHCI by removing your (wrong) type signature.

Function `selectFieldList` should getting data from static list without any IO.

Best way is using function `selectField`. You should look to it's type:

`selectField ::(Eq a, RenderMessage site FormMessage) =>
  HandlerT site IO (OptionList a) -> Field (HandlerT site IO) a`

I.e. you can use something like

`selectList (fmap convertYourListToOptionList findAllAsTuple)`

Comment: I do not understand the "convertYourListToOptionList" function. Please write down.